# Accessing child orderable attribute in page model template

Tags: python, jinja2, wagtail

The [wagtail documentation](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html#parents-and-children) outlines how to iterate over an orderable property in a page template, however, if I try the same from the parent page, whilst iterating on the children, I am unable to access the children's page orderable prop

Ex:

```
{% for post in page.get_children %}

        <div class="max-w-sm bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
            <a href="{% pageurl post %}">
                {% for item in post.gallery_images.all %}
                    {% image item.image fill-320x240 as img %}
                        <img
                            alt="{{ item.caption }}"
                            class="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                            src="{{ img.url }}" />
                    <img class="rounded-t-lg" src="{{ img.url }}" alt="{{ img.url }}" class="carousel-img"/>
                    <p class="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">{{ img.url  }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
            </a>
            <div class="p-5">
                <a href="{% pageurl post %}">
                    <h5 class="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white">{{ post.title }}</h5>
                </a>
                <p class="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">Here are the biggest enterprise technology acquisitions of 2021 so far, in reverse chronological order.</p>
                <a href="#" class="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-center text-white bg-blue-700 rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">
                    Read more
                    <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-4 h-4 ml-2 -mr-1" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.293 3.293a1 1 0 011.414 0l6 6a1 1 0 010 1.414l-6 6a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L14.586 11H3a1 1 0 110-2h11.586l-4.293-4.293a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

I'm basically trying to access the img url's to display the children's images from the parent (index page)